# The gallery images repeated in PDP page

Tags: image, gallery, thumbnail

In My PDP page, the thumbnail images which is shown on the bottom side of the product image are displayed twice

Please refer below screenshot, It repeats the product image twice in bottom[image]

Comment: Have u check your screenshot properly. Images two are different

Comment: you can remove another image in the admin product configuration page

Comment: See i have updated the image

Comment: In backend i have uploaded only one image